# Why do Browsers crash on my machine with Nvidia Drivers?

Tags: linux, nvidia, hardware, firefox, ram

For a while now on my system browsers crash very often (between 3 times in a row when opening and once every hour). Sometimes the entire browser crashes, sometimes its only one tab. I normally use Firefox but Chromium Browsers crash in seemingly the same way.
I assume this happens because of Nvidia proprietary Drivers because everything works before installing them or when using Nouveau Drivers.

Browsers: Firefox, Brave, Chromium

OS: Fedora, EndeavourOS, PopOS with Nvidia Drivers preinstalled

Kernels: everything from Stable older kernels to newest ones

Hardware:

- Nvidia GTX 1650 Super
- AMD Ryzen 7 5700g
- ASRock Fatal1ty B450 Motherboard
- Crucial P3 1 TB SSD

Crash reasons given by Firefox:

- index out of bounds: the len is 63 but the index is 4103
- no entry found for key
- running Firefox from CLI gives me this:

```
   signal 11: file
   /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:265
[Parent 13845, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 14620 exited on signal 11: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:265
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 14783
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Failed to open curl lib from binary, use libcurl.so instead
```

I have tried switching OS and browsers, running Firefox in troubleshoot mode, installing the Driver in different ways, running different Kernels, understanding error messages.

Can I somehow troubleshoot this issue?

Edit 1: Output of dmesg

```
[   25.094695] audit: type=1400 audit(1704318740.132:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=930 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.094700] audit: type=1400 audit(1704318740.132:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=930 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.207561] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   25.207575] nvidia: module license taints kernel.
[   25.226226] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input11
[   25.226525] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input12
[   25.226663] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input13
[   25.226777] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input14
[   25.319491] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 511
[   25.320706] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[   25.368293] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  545.29.06  Thu Nov 16 01:59:08 UTC 2023
[   25.378744] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  545.29.06  Thu Nov 16 01:47:29 UTC 2023
[   25.382645] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[   26.447537] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   26.459014] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[   26.505991] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 509.
```

Edit 2: Memtest

Memtest gave me about 20000 errors. I updated my BIOS and used the BIOS default settings for RAM instead of the XMP profile. Both steps showed the same errors. Now I am testing with only 1 of 2 16GB RAM sticks which seems to work. So either the one that I took out is faulty or having both in results in problems. Memtests are still running and I will update later

Edit 3:

One of my RAM sticks resulted in errors, the other didn't in the same socket. I removed it and right now, Firefox is running fine.

Edit 4:

Everything works perfectly. Browsers don't crash, System in general runs way better and I haven't had a single unexpected thing happening since fixing this.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i -E 'nvrm|nvidia'`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Just did that

Comment: I'm inclined to believe you're dealing with a HW error. That doesn't look like your GPU, so it might be your RAM (run memtest86+ for at least a couple of cycles).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov One RAM Stick is faulty, you are correct. Thank you so much for your help! If you post your idea as an answer I can accept it

Comment: A bad RAM stick can cause *all sorts* of issues. Disk writes go thru RAM, so you probably have a bunch of corrupted files on your drive. Hope you kept backups!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not your GPU, please test your RAM using either [memtest86+](https://memtest.org/) or [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) for at least a couple of cycles.